# How to make Test App links work

Tags: android-studio, deep-linking, applinks

The following is the App Links Assistant in Android Studio (V2.3.3)
[image]

Clicking Test App Links generating IndexOutOfBoundsException as shown at the bottom left corner of AS:
[image]

Could anyone offer a tip on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading Android Studio to v3.0 fixing this issue.